# Printing Specific Bytes from Pcap file in XML Format

Tags: python, pcap, pyshark

I have an array called "red_regions" that contains the positions of specific hexadecimal bytes from a Pcap file. I am able to print out those bytes in Hexadcimal Format, however, I would like to print them out in Human-Readable format from the pcap file.

When I open the pcap file in Wireshark, I am able to check each Hexadecimal byte (from the bottom-right panel) and see what it corresponds to in the pcap file (from the bottom-left panel). For instance, **byte-positions 11, 12, 13, 14** in the Hexadecimal representation correspond to **"Ethernet Layer: Source: Cisco_14:eb:31, Address: Cisco_14:eb:31 (00:c1:b1:14:eb:31)"**.

I can do the same thing for the other bytes, however, I have a large dataset, and doing that manually will take a very long time. I would like to know if it is possible to create a script to automate the process and print out the correspondence for every position in the "red_regions" array. (I am currently using Python.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.